# Using user defined parameters to control auto-scaling of AWS ELB instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

We have an application which is deployed on AWS ELB.

Currently, auto-scaling is configured to use the aggregate CPU across the ELB instances to automatically add / remove ELB instances.

However, it would be more accurate if we could interrogate the queue lengths on the RabbitMQ instance which is accessed by the ELB instances. Then scale up / down when the queue lengths exceed a threshold.

Is there any way of configuring ELBs to introduce new parameters which could be derived from, for arguments sake, a web service call, which could then be used to control auto-scaling?

Or, do we have to just bite the bullet, and develop our own auto-scaler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) is based on Amazon [CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch) metrics. CloudWatch initially provided predefined metrics only, but [meanwhile custom metrics can be managed](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/05/amazon-cloudwatch-user-defined-metrics.html) as well.

Consequently you can implement your scenario by [publishing a custom CloudWatch metric](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/publishingMetrics.html) tracking the queue lengths of the RabbitMQ instance in question and scale up / down according to an arbitrary scaling policy based on a respective [CloudWatch Alarm](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingWithAWSProducts.html#as_monitors) monitoring this metric.